# How to take the $\log$ of $e$ when taken to the power of a matrix?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes-classifier

I'm having some troubles trying to solve the following question, I'm trying to find the $C$ which maximizes
$$\begin{align}\text{arg max}_{1\geq m\geq K}(\log p(\mathbf{x}|C_m)+log P(C_m))\end{align}$$
as I'm not too familiar with the $e$ superscript notations, I think it's representing a matrix, and the decision boundary might end up being a circle,  I'm not sure how to reduce which probability is greater?

Full problem description below:

A generative classifier is used for a binary classification problem, where the classes are $C_1$ and $C_2$. The input consists of two features: $x_1$ and $x_2$. taking values in $\Bbb{R}$. The prior probability of $C_1$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. The class conditional probability density functions are
$$
p(x_1,x_2|t=C_1)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{(x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2\}}\\
p(x_1,x_2|t=C_2)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{2x_1^2+2x_2^2\}}
$$

Determine the decision boundary and the decision rule of the classifier.

$$\log p(x_1,x_2|t=C_1)+\log P(C_1)= \log(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{(x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2\}})+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}log(2)-log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}(x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$= log(2)-2log(2\pi)-(x_1-1)^2+4(x_2-2)^2+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$=-(x_1^2-2x_1+1)+4(x_2^2-4x_2+4)+\log(2)-2\log(2\pi)+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$=-x_1^2+2x_1-1+4x_2^2-16x_2+16+\log(2)-2\log(2\pi)+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$=-x_1^2+2x_1+4x_2^2-16x_2+10.92 $$
$$\log p(x_1,x_2|t=C_2)+\log P(C_2)= \log(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{2x_1^2+2x_2^2\}})+\log(\frac{2}{3})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}log(2)-log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}(2x_1^2+2x_2^2)= log(2)-2log(2\pi)-2x_1^2+2x_2^2+\log{\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$=-2x_1^2+2x_2^2-0.67= -2x_1^2+4x_2^2-3.39$$

The decision boundary would be when these two formulas are equal, does it mean I should look at applying a radial basis function?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a correct solution, no need for a radial basis function:

$$\log p(x_1,x_2|t=C_1)+\log P(C_1)= \log(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{(x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2\}})+\log(\frac{1}{3})$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}((x_1-1)^2+2(x_2-2)^2)+\log1-\log3$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-2x_1+1+2(x_2^2-4x_2+4))-\log3$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-2x_1+2x_2^2-8x_2+9)-\log3$$

$$\log p(x_1,x_2|t=C_2)+\log P(C_2)= \log(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\{2x_1^2+2x_2^2\}})+\log(\frac{2}{3})$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}(2x_1^2+2x_2^2)+\log2-\log3$$
Decision boundary:
$$\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-2x_1+2x_2^2-8x_2+9)-\log3= \frac{1}{2}\log2-\log2\pi-\frac{1}{2}(2x_1^2+2x_2^2)+\log2-\log3$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-2x_1+2x_2^2-8x_2+9)= -\frac{1}{2}(2x_1^2+2x_2^2)+\log2$$
$$x_1^2-2x_1+2x_2^2-8x_2+9= 2x_1^2+2x_2^2-2\log2$$
$$-8x_2+9= x_1^2-2x_1-2\log2$$
$$x_2=-\frac{1}{8}(x_1^2-2x_1-9-2\log2)$$
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\begin{cases}
C_1&\text{if }x_2 \leq -\frac{1}{8}(x_1^2-2x_1-9-2\log2)\\
C_0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$